# Jackson deserialize map or single value?

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

We have an object with a field that contains a map of type string -> List. We would like to add support for a new wildcard in the json data that we are de-serializing so that

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "thing": "blah",
  "mapField": "*"
}
```

gets de-serialized as if it were

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "thing": "blah",
  "mapField": {
    "*": ["*"]
  }
}
```

Our class def looks like:

```
@Value
@Builder
@JsonDeserialize(builder = FooBar.FooBarBuilder.class)
public class FooBar {
  private final String id;
  private final String thing;
  private final Map<String, List<String>> mapField;

  @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
  public static final class FooBarBuilder {
  }
}
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this without having to write a custom de-serializer?

We do not have control over the format of the data flowing in, so making the change on that side isn't really possible. I tried updating the builder class with a new method:

```
public FooBarBuilder withMapField(String thing) {
      if ("*".equals(thing)) {
        this.mapField = new HashMap<>();
        this.mapField.put("*", List.of("*"));
      }
      return this;
}
```

but am still seeing errors during de-serialization:
`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of "java.util.LinkedHashMap" (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('*')`

Comment: You could define your field as `Object` and then build the map in the getter or setter (or constructor).

Comment: What's the problem with a custom deserializer?

Comment: I personally just don't love custom deserializers. I don't have a ton of experience with them, but I feel like anytime I try to write one it ends up being convoluted and hard to follow, especially compared to the benefit